# OPENGL c++ animated particles

Tags: c++, opengl, system, particles

So I am using the project here: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/particles-instancing/#Animated_particles

as the basis for my particle system. about 2/3 down that page it says:

"Going further

Animated particles

You can animate your particles’ texture with a texture atlas. Send the age of each particle along with the position, and in the shaders, compute the UVs like we did for the 2D font tutorial. A texture atlas looks like this :"

Now what I want to is how do I send in the age individually for each particle to the shader? As the particles are all instanced together would the shader not receive a single age for all the particles?

Comment: send a per-particle age along with the per-particle position.

Comment: How would I do that? another VBO?

Comment: yeah, you could use another vbo with a new attribute variable in the shader. I would suggest using the attribute variable to hold the creation time and use a new uniform to hold the current time so you would only need to update the vbo when you create new particles instead of every frame.

Answer (score 0):

Programmerjake wrote:

> Yeah, you could use another vbo with a new attribute variable in the
>   shader. I would suggest using the attribute variable to hold the
>   creation time and use a new uniform to hold the current time so you
>   would only need to update the vbo when you create new particles
>   instead of every frame.